# Congratulations to MVP Group 2017 2

Tags: discussion, mvp

[Salesforce MVP Group Announcement](https://www.salesforce.com/blog/2017/09/welcome-28-new-salesforce-mvps.html)

Congratulations to the new MVPs including Adam Spriggs and Christian Szandor Knapp from our user base and the others who maintained their status.

Comment: Congrats to Adam Spriggs and Christian Szandor Knapp and existing mvps. We wish we would see more mvps from SFSE in future!

Comment: Go Adam!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Congrats Adam and Christian.

Comment: Thanks, everyone!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Congratulations Adam Spriggs and Christian Szandor Knapp .

Very well deserved and thanks for your amazing contributions to the salesforce.stackexchange.com community and keeping the spirit of Salesforce ohana.

Comment: Is good to see SFSE well represented once again!

Answer (score 8):

Congrats Adam Spriggs and Christian Szandor Knapp - glad to see the Salesforce Stack Exchange flag flying high yet again in the MVP community! Congrats to existing fellow MVPs who got renewed!

Hope to meet most of you at Dreamforce this year!

Comment: Congrats Gaurav for your renewal as well.

Comment: congrats for you too :)

Answer (score 8):

Thank you all - I'm very humbled and grateful! Let's keep this SE the great place it is!

Answer (score 5):

I second Christian's sentiments.  It's been a surprising whirlwind of emotion!

(Mostly, like, "OK, what do I do now?")

Hat-tip to the ET Developer Advocates I met at Connections in 2014 in Indy -- the ones that got `marketing-cloud` rolling and inspired me to pitch in and help.

Thanks, [@kellyjandrews](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/4786/kelly-j-andrews) and [@timothy](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/7419/timothy).

Comment: Congrats, Adam!

Answer (score 2):

Congrats Adam, Christian and Existing MVPs who got Renewed.Thanks everyone for sharing your knowledge and helping others in the community.